# duplicate files during packaging of APK, libpjsua2.so

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-studio, pjsip

I got this error Duplicate files during packaging of APK app-debug-unaligned.apk when migrate project from Eclipse to Android studio:

```
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK C:\Users\aaa\AndroidStudioProjects\Pjsua2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: lib/armeabi/libpjsua2.so
    Origin 1: C:\Users\aaa\AndroidStudioProjects\Pjsua2\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi\libpjsua2.so
    Origin 2: C:\Users\aaa\AndroidStudioProjects\Pjsua2\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib\armeabi\libpjsua2.so
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
    android {
      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/armeabi/libpjsua2.so'
      }
    }
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK lib/armeabi/libpjsua2.so
    File 1: C:\Users\aaa\AndroidStudioProjects\Pjsua2\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi\libpjsua2.so
    File 2: C:\Users\aaa\AndroidStudioProjects\Pjsua2\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi\libpjsua2.so
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

I tried to change build.gradle, but anything get same error.
My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.pjsip.pjsua2.app"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 15

        ndk {
            moduleName "libpjsua2"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me fix.

Answer (score 1):

I see from your path that 'jniLibs' is inside 'src/main'.  This means that the .so file is included when compiling source.

Move the 'armeabi\libpjsua2.so' folder out into a folder called 'libs' inside the 'Pjsua2\app\' folder (i.e. move it out to the base app folder).

Your .so file would then be in:
Pjsua2\app\libs\armeabi\libpjsua2.so

Then add the following in your gradle.build's "android" closure:

```
android {
...
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
    }
}
```

This may fix the problem of double counting (worked for me).

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, would you be able to update your answer with your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and finally got it working by deleting the following in build.gradle

```
        ndk {
        moduleName "libpjsua2"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete jni folder (and two files inside: Android.mk & Application.mk) in your Android Studio imported project.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hi Jaiprakash: My answer "delete jni folder" does solve his "Duplicate files" problem. This works for me.

You can try it too by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

@Yervant Thanks for tip, it helped a lot! 
One more comment for future users: after moving libs I have encountered another problem `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.swig_module_init:()`. Solution for that was to move pjsip classes into separate package and update imports. Simple as hell but took me whole day to figure it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've just managed to successfully import pjsua2 into Android Studio so maybe I can help. From what I understand the jni folder contains 2 files that attempt to rebuild the library again creating the second instance. Removing your pre-made one by moving jniLibs will work but I don't particularly trust Android Studio to build it correctly, therefore, I just remove the two files inside the jni folder and the problem was solved.

The jni folder for myself was in the directory app/src/main/jni

I could be completely wrong above but it worked for me so I made a few assumptions.